# Angular google map change origin latitude and longitude

Tags: angular, google-maps

How to change origin latitude and longitude in angular google maps? Also how to refresh the map every 5 seconds? or should i provide a refresh button for the user?

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.getPosition();
  this.getAgentsLocationNow();

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(this.currentLocation.lat, this.currentLocation.lng)
  });
}
getAgentsLocationNow() {
  this.http.getAgentsLocationNow()
    .subscribe((result) => {
      this.agentslocations = result;
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}

geocodeAddress() {
  var address = this.searchtext;
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {

    if (status === 'OK') {

      this.currentLocation = {};
      this.currentLocation.lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      this.currentLocation.lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

      map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(this.currentLocation.lat, this.currentLocation.lng));


    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<agm-map [usePanning]='true' [latitude]="currentLocation.lat" [longitude]="currentLocation.lng" [zoom]="8">
  <agm-marker *ngFor="let agentLoc of agentslocations" [latitude]="agentLoc.Latitude" [longitude]="agentLoc.Longitude" [label]="agentLoc.Agent" [title]="agentLoc.Agent">
  </agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

I am using AGM library
Thank you in Advance.

Comment: what have you done so far? you need to share the code that you have basically done so far and stuck.

Comment: 1) As mentioned above, please show your code and what you have tried, as well as if you are using a library or the built in ```maps``` component
2) Google Maps Dynamic API is no longer free. You get, I believe, 150,000 free Map loads a month. Refreshing every 5 seconds might get expensive (and annoying for the user) pretty fast. 
3) Please read the docs, information like this is easy to find on google maps API